# Запятая на стыке союзе

Tags: запятые

Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись, и если прочитал, то каково его мнение о ней — союз *и* соединяет соподчиненные придаточные части;

таково объяснение у Розенталя.

Если же изменить так:

Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись и, если прочитал, каково его мнение о ней — союз *и* соединяет соподчиненные придаточные части;

Правильно ли здесь расставлены запятые?

Comment: Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись, и если прочитал, то каково его мнение о ней.


Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись и, если прочитал, каково его мнение о ней.

Отличаются ли эти предложения по смыслу?

Comment: Думаю, по смыслу они не отличаются. Но запятая помогает понять смысл при разных конструкциях. Во втором случае она указывает на то, что И соединяет "прочитал ли рецензент рукопись" и "каково его мнение". В первом предложении она помогает избежать ошибки восприятия И как соединяющего "прочитал ли рецензент рукопись" и "если прочитал".

Answer (score 2):

Если решать задачу без правил по Розенталю или других правил, а только по грамматике, то в этом предложении я вижу два варианта:

(1) Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись и если прочитал, то каково его мнение о ней.

(2)Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись и, если прочитал, каково его мнение о ней.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

А. Перед И запятой нет, так как здесь однородное соподчинение.

Б. После И запятая ставится/не ставится в зависимости от наличия двойного союза ЕСЛИ...ТО. На постановку запятой перед И форма этого союза не влияет.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно правилам пунктуации при встрече соединительного союза *и* и подчинительного союза запятая ставится только перед союзом *и* (**независимо от того, соединяет ли он однородные члены предложения, самостоятельные предложения или соподчиненные придаточные части**), если после придаточной части следует **вторая часть двойного союза** *то, как* или *но* (**в этом случае союз *и* присоединяет целое сложноподчиненное предложение**):

1. О*н носил тёмные очки, фуфайку, уши закладывал ватой, **и когда** садился на извозчика, **то** приказывал поднимать верх (Ч.)* — союз и соединяет однородные члены предложения;
2. *Изредка маленькая снежинка прилипала снаружи к стеклу, **и если** пристально вглядеться, **то** можно было увидеть её тончайшее кристаллическое строение* (Пауст.) — союз и соединяет простые предложения;
3. *Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись, **и если** прочитал, **то** каково его мнение о ней* — союз и соединяет соподчиненные придаточные части.

То есть все перечисленные случаи рассматриваются как присоединение сложноподчиненного предложения. Если не поставить запятую перед И, исказится смысл, так как придаточное "прилипнет" к предыдущей части. Сравните:

1. Уши закладывал ватой и когда садился на извозчика (на самом деле союз И соединяет *уши закладывал ватой* и *приказывал поднимать верх, когда садился на извозчика*).
2. Снежинка прилипала снаружи к стеклу и если пристально вглядеться.
3. Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись и если прочитал (то есть даже если прочитал, выясните, прочитал ли).

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, правильно: союз "и" соединяет два однородных придаточных предложения, поэтому запятая перед "и" не нужна, а после "и" необходима.

Comment: Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись и каково его мнение о ней.

Здесь соподчиненные части: прочитал рецензент, каково его мнение?

но между соподчиненными частями, соединенными союзом И, запятая не ставится.

тогда почему же в предложении

Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись, и если прочитал, то каково его мнение о ней 

запятая стоит?

Comment: А в каком источнике она стоит? В тесте ЕГЭ?

Answer (score 1):

> Выясните, пожалуйста, прочитал ли рецензент рукопись и каково его мнение о ней.

Запятая не ставится, т.к. здесь однородные придаточные(как и между однородными членами с одиночным союзом И зпт не ставится.)
В нашем случае можно использовать подсказку: есть ТО - нет запятой, нет ТО - есть запятая